# mv command confuses directory name with command option

Tags: linux, mv

I have a directory called `--pycache--`, which I need to move to `__pycache__`. Using the `mv` command in the following way, gives me the listed output. How can I use the `CLI` to do what I want?

```
$ mv --pycache-- __pycache__
/bin/mv: unrecognized option '--pycache--/'
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a standard issue with filenames/directories starting with less conventional symbols. Your problem is that mv is treating --pycache-- as long option name (since it starts with --, there are also short options, they start with -). Please see manpage for **getopt** for details about long and short options.

The standard workaround in this situation is to use an empty double dash **--** before all argument, which tells the command (mv in your case, but will work with others, cp for example) to stop treating what follows as options and treat it as arguments.

Thus, your command will become:

```
$ mv -- --pycache--/ __pycache__
```

and won't fail.

Comment: good answer but I think you mean *--* tells the command to stop treating what follows as options and treat it as arguments, not the other way round.

Comment: I think it's more portable to prepend `./`: `mv ./--pycache-- __pycache__`.

Comment: @Kevin That works only if the argument is a file name.

Answer (score 16):

Your first character `-` is ambiguous for the `mv` command (or rather, it unambiguously means that an option name follows).

Try this instead:

```
mv ./--ppycache-- __pycache__
```

Source: [linux.about.com](http://linux.about.com/od/linux101/l/blnewbie3_1_1.htm)

Comment: +1 for alternate solution that also works if the command does not support --